# What is the difference between @order and @DependsOn annotations in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

one can use annotations like `@Order` to specify order in which beans are created. Similarly, we use `@DependsOn` if we want one bean to be created after the another.
What is the exact difference between these two annotations? Can we use them interchangeably?

Comment: They serve a different purpose, so can you use them interchangeably no you cannot nor should. If you have a bean which depends on another one add the `@DependsOn` the `@Order` is no guarantee (as it might apply to a list of beans). Although generally when configured properly you don't need the `@DependsOn`.

Comment: @m-deinum, can't we use '@DependsOn' to create the chain in which one beans gets created after the other, can't we specify order in this way? Then what purpose the '@order' serve? Aren't both the same thing?

Comment: As stated no they aren't. `@Order` is also used in the initi order of beans, or when you retrieve all the beans of a type from the context the resulting list is ordered in that way. So no they aren't different things and when there is a dependency between beans, the order might nog even be applied.